# Collator: how to add space to the rules?

Tags: java, sorting, collator

I'm using a custom collator to sort strings according to the hungarian grammar rulers, but it seems, for some reason, Java thinks that 'Budapesti' is greater than 'Budapest' (the first means from Budapest).

Here is my current rule for the custom collator:

```
String hungarianRules = (
            "< 0 < 1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5 < 6 < 7 < 8 < 9" +
            "< a,A < á,Á < b,B < c,C < d,D < e,E < é,É < f,F < g,G < h,H < i,I < í,Í < j,J < k,K < l,L < m,M < n,N " +
            "< o,O < ó,Ó < ö,Ö < ő,Ő < p,P < q,Q < r,R < s,S < t,T < u,U < ú,Ú < ü,Ü < ű,Ű < v,V < w,W " +
            "< x,X < y,Y < z,Z < \u0020 " );
```

But if I try to use this rule to process the strings, I get the following exception:

```
Java.text.ParseException: missing chars (=,;<&): 
    at java.text.PatternEntry$Parser.next(PatternEntry.java:276)
```

From what I understood this is because the processing reaches the 'space' character between 2 words in the same string (like 'Budapest Állami Levéltár').

Is there a way to add the value of space to the custom collator rules?

Comment: You could try the ASCII code - \x20

Comment: If I add it just like this: " ... < z,Z < \\x20 " it will give Unquoted punctation character 5c error, which is the \ - but that is needed in order to put the ascii value in the string. Is there another way, maybe create a variable with ASCII value?

Comment: I had to add it to the start of the ruleset, but it's working. Now onto other problems that arose... God, I hate my language...

Answer (score 1):

The ASCII code \x20 represents a space. Use the value \\x20 as the value for a space.( \\ to escape the literal)